# Why my Center widget doesn't work in Dart? | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, row, center

i am trying to Center all widgets (2 Icons and Text), but when i am adding Center widget (Before child: row i put child: Center(*code below*)), nothing happens, 0 errors, it's just not working.

```
Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.outbond_outlined,
          color: Colors.amber,
          size: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 220.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.call_end_sharp,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            const Text(
              "Skrt",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontFamily: "Lato"),
            ),
            const Icon(
              Icons.call_end_sharp,
              color: Colors.amber,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Hi Malak, Looks like there are two widgets containers. are these in column or row ? and where are you using center widget?

Comment: There are in Wrap

Comment: I am using it before this second Container, with width 220.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, in your Row

example:

```
Row(
      // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        const Icon(
          Icons.call_end_sharp,
          color: Colors.amber,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
        const Text(
          "Skrt",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 30.0,
              fontFamily: "Lato"),
        ),
        const Icon(
          Icons.call_end_sharp,
          color: Colors.amber,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Welcome Bro!  :)